# Chrome Kiosk App Keeping user's within domain

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, whitelist, blacklist, kiosk-mode

I'm creating a Chrome Kiosk App to allow user's to search our database for books so it's pretty much a library search system.
It uses our homepage of our website where the universal search bar is. When you type in a title, it searches the database and displays results in Book format, Audio format, etc.

However, I want to make sure that they stay within the domain name so they can't go to playboy.com or any other website for that matter.

This is my HTML so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="browser.css">
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="browser.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="controls">
      <button id="back" title="Go Back">&#9664;</button>
      <button id="forward" title="Go Forward">&#9654;</button>
      <button id="home" title="Go Home">&#8962;</button>
      <button id="reload" title="Reload">&#10227;</button>
      <form id="location-form">
        <div id="center-column">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <webview src="https://thesmartstore.org/in-house-search" style="width:100%; height:100%"></webview>
    <div id="sad-webview">
      <div id="sad-webview-icon">&#9762;</div>
      <h2 id="crashed-label">Aw, Snap!</h2>
      <h2 id="killed-label">He's Dead, Jim!</h2>

      <p>Something went wrong while displaying this webpage.
      To continue, reload or go to another page.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Javascript is pretty heavy, but I was wondering if there was a way to whitelist just this domain or make sure they stay on https://thesmartstore.org/ domain. As long as the beginning of the url starts with this, they should be good, if not, I will redirect them to the homepage.

Since the Javascript is quite large, I pasted it in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/UecgS4sQ

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

A better option rather than requesting a url and trusting the users we can use ajax and then get a response back with our json

```
function navigateTo(search) {
  resetExitedState();
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //any request headers
  //ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
     if (ajax.status === 200) {
        //make a function to process the JSON
        processJSON();
      } else {
         alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  };
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('q',search);
  httpRequest.open('POST', 'https://thesmartstore.org/search.php', true);
  httpRequest.send(formData);
}
```

Comment: No you can inspect element on Chrome Kiosk apps and fire `window.location.href = 'http://google.com/'` and search whatever you like. That's what I'm trying to avoid. A complete domain change. And it seems the webview tag needs to be able to be edited since that's what controls the navigation of the chrome kiosk app. They're pretty funky development wise..

Comment: Well I'm not 100% sure what the kiosk app is compared to the other apps, I'm reading on it now. If it's like a chrome app you can right click during dev mode but not during release. Though then again if I really wanted to go to `www.playboy.com` I'd just go to it instead of trying to do it through your app

Comment: Yeah have you tried other kiosk apps? As far as I know in the Chrome OS which my screen on my chromebook is broken that we can't right click or inspect anyways in the app, only while in dev mode. And if you do my second suggestion it'll eliminate all the fuss and buss of trying to prevent all this.

Comment: lol true. My workplace wanted me to do a whitelist thing on here, but I honestly don't think it's necessary and I don't even know if it's possible in Javascript is it? I mean once they navigate off your site, your JS doesn't apply anymore I don't think..

Comment: No JavaScript is local to the site. If you are using a chrome app though you can control the webview still. Especially in the background.js

Comment: If you are creating a library to search through we should really create an ajax call with JSON response.

Comment: Hmm ok. So you can set filters with the webview tag? To make sure it's always on the same domain in background.js? The search goes through SolR and JQuery.. it's a huge monster. This chrome app is literally just referring to the library's main website homepage. So all the functionality exists on the server side, not on the chrome app.

Comment: Yes I get that. If you need more assistance we can discuss this else where. If you really want to constantly test you can create a loop testing the href. Though I'm not sure how efficient it'll be. Anyways the logic behind this I don't think is well thought through so maybe I'm missing something but like I said I don't mind discussing this in further detail else where as to not create an extended discussion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66420/discussion-between-haleybuggs-and-easybb).

Answer (score 0):

Handle the webview's `loadstart` event. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview

Comment: A short sample would be appreciated, otherwise this qualifies as link-only.

Comment: I don't have a sample; I've never used the event myself. Go ahead and downvote it if that's the better outcome.